# Merging two cursors in Oracle 19C in optimal way

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle19c

I have two complex stored procedures for fetching data for pagination. Along with other input parameters, both have startIndex and PageSize which will give fixed number of records. Now I have a requirement where I need to merge the result of both procedures and store in a single cursor. Basically show paginated data from both procedure, but in single cursor. I did the following based on various posts I found -

1. Called Proc_First(...params, startIndex=0, pageSize=INF, out_cursor_1);
2. Called Proc_Second(...params, startIndex=0, pageSize=INF, out_cursor_2);
3. Used loop to iterate over out_cursor_1 and out_cursor_2 and stored in a table type, say R1 & R2
4. Opened final cursor as: select * from (select * from table(R1) union select * from table(R2)) where rownum >= startIndex AND rownum <= (startIndex + pageSize);

Now I have a doubt that I am basically fetching entire data from both procedures and then fetching the paginated data. It may cause performance issues later. One way I thought of was, to use the queries in both procedures and put union there itself. But those queries are too old and complex that rewriting them will be a big mess now.

I want to handle cases like - Proc_1 has 8 records and Proc_2 has 5 records. If pageSize is 10, it should show me data in page 1 (10 records) and page 2 (3 records) without missing any record. Is there a better approach to achieve this?

Comment: Is there a need to jump to pages?

Comment: Only buttons are there to increase the startIndex. Means it will be 1 initially and then it will be 11 in next page if pagesize is 10. There is no case where index will start from a random number in between.

Comment: Then it could be suitable to always page both cursor, merge the two pages, pick pagezize rows and set startindexes accordingly, i.E. startindex1 = 6 startindex2 =4 if 6 records are from cursor1 and 4 from cursor2 in the first 10 records. Similrar scolling backwards...

Comment: Yes. But I am a bit confused on how to divide the startIndex and pagesize among both queries so that I always get consistent results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> One way I thought of was, to use the queries in both procedures and put union there itself.

That is the way to go.

> But those queries are too old and complex that rewriting them will be a big mess now.

Then don't rewrite then, copy them and wrap them in a sub-query factoring clause (`WITH` clause) and just re-use them:

```sql
WITH query1 ( list_of_column_aliases ) AS (
  your_first_query
),
query2 ( list_of_column_aliases ) AS (
  your_second_query
),
combined_query ( list_of_column_aliases ) AS (
  SELECT * FROM query1
UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM query2
ORDER BY something
),
paged_query ( list_of_column_aliases, rn ) AS (
  SELECT cq.*, ROWNUM
  FROM   combined_query cq
  WHERE  ROWNUM < start_index + page_size
)
SELECT list_of_column_aliases
FROM   paged_query
WHERE  rn >= start_index;
```

Comment: Let me try. Thanks for this suggestion.

Comment: I wasn't sure wether the procs were really only queries with no logic around. If not that's surely the way...

Comment: @Turo yes thats the issue. Procs have other local variables and multiple queries. If there were 4-5 queries it was still fine but I have hundreds of local variables and queries here before the main query. That's why I went with my loop approach . If any suggestions over optimisation please let me know